# <form:input> name attribute appears double time while rendering

Tags: jsp

Here is the HTML before rendering

```
<form:select id="eventName" class="form-control  select2" style="width: 100%; 
                    -webkit-appearance: none;" name="event" path="eventName" >
   <form:option value="0" selected="selected">Select a category</form:option>
   <c:forEach var="eventName2" items="${listDropDown}">
       <form:option  value="${eventName2.eventId}">${eventName2.eventName}</form:option>
   </c:forEach>
</form:select>
```

I used name attribute form:input single time but it appears double while rendered in the browser as below:

```
<select id="eventName" name="eventName" name="event" style="width: 100%; 
       -webkit-appearance: none;" class="form-control  select2">
```

Any one please answer why it appears twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You have to use path attribute only without using name attribute*. As the browser will translate `path="eventName"` to `name="eventName"`.